# How to output a counter with leading zeros?

Tags: formatting, counters

I can output the value of a counter in a LaTeX document via:

```
\setcounter{mycounter}{1}
\arabic{mycounter}
```

Which inserts a `1`. But how do I format the output by, for example, adding a leading zero if `mycounter` is less than 10 in a way similar to what [`printf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) lets you do by specifying `%02d` as your format string?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The principle is

```
\ifnum\value{mycounter}<10 0\fi\arabic{mycounter}
```

How to implement it into your macros depends on how and where you want to use this representation.

Comment: I want to use it as an argument to `\Opensolutionfile{ans}[prefixCOUNTER]` which is part of the `answers` package. And your approach works fine in that context.

Comment: an equally robust (because it is based on the same principle) but much more general solution is provided by the [`animate`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/animate) package as the command `\@anim@pad` It can be used as `\makeatletter\@anim@pad{\mynumber}{\arabic{mycounter}}\makeatother` provided `\usepackage{animate}` is included in the preamble.

Answer (score 44):

The [`fmtcount` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/fmtcount) provide a variety of ways to format counter (even changing the base to binary or octal, rather than decimal, say). To prepend a bunch of zeroes to a counter, use `\padzeroes[<n>]{\decimal{<cntr>}}`. This will add zeroes `0` in front of the counter `<cntr>` such that the eventual length is `<n>`. `\decimal{<cntr>}` is similar to `\arabic{<cntr>}` but is required to work with `\padzeroes`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fmtcount}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fmtcount
\begin{document}
\newcounter{mycounter}%
\newcommand{\printcntr}{%
  \stepcounter{mycounter}%
  \padzeroes[2]{\decimal{mycounter}} &
  \padzeroes[4]{\binary{mycounter}} &
  \padzeroes[3]{\octal{mycounter}}%
}

\begin{tabular}{ccc}
  \textbf{Decimal} & \textbf{Binary} & \textbf{Octal} \\ \hline
  \printcntr \\ \printcntr \\ \printcntr \\ \printcntr \\ \printcntr \\
  \printcntr \\ \printcntr \\ \printcntr \\ \printcntr \\ \printcntr
\end{tabular}  
\end{document}
```

[image: Counters in different bases, with prepended zeroes 0]

Comment: Just a note: `\padzeroes` seems to be a `\protected` macro, so you cannot do stuff like `\edef\mypad{\padzeroes[2]{5}}` - Latex will complain about `! Undefined control sequence`.

Comment: Any idea how to use `\padzeroes` such as in `\immediate\write\file{\padzeroes[3]{\decimal{<countername>}}`, i.e. to export it to a file? I get `! Use of \@item doesn't match its definition.
`... maybe it is related to the above comment...

Comment: @anderstood: How about [these options](https://pastebin.com/VUwpqKfH)...?

Comment: @Werner Yes, that's basically egreg's suggestion, which I have used. I did not manage with `\padzeroes` nor `pgf`. Does not matter but I was curious why!

Answer (score 35):

LaTeX knows a macro `\two@digits`

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{mycounter}
\makeatletter     
\renewcommand\themycounter{\two@digits{\value{mycounter}}}     
\makeatother     

\newcommand\Test{\stepcounter{mycounter}\themycounter\ }
\begin{document}
\Test
\Test
\Test

\end{document}
```

Comment: Just a note: `\two@digits` seems not to be `\protected` - and thus expandable; so you can do stuff like `\makeatletter\edef\mypad{\two@digits{5}}\makeatother` (to store its output in a command).

Comment: it should be `\newcommand\themycounter{\two@digits{\value{reqCounter}}}`, otherwise LaTeX returns `LaTeX Error: Command \themycounter undefined.` (at least for me)

Answer (score 17):

If you use LuaTeX, you can do this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\newcounter{mycounter}
\setcounter{mycounter}{10}
\newcommand\print[1]{%
  \directlua{
     tex.sprint(string.format("\%02d",\arabic{#1}))
  }
}
\print{mycounter}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 14):

You could use `pgf` for this. It has a `\pgfmathsetbasenumberlength` setting used for the base conversion macros. Setting it to 2 and do a dummy conversion the counter value to base 10 will give you `01`, `02`, ..., `10`, etc. It also scales well, i.e. you can just use 3 and get `001`, etc. However, for smaller things I would use egreg's solution instead.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgf}

\newcounter{mycounter}
\newcommand\test{{%
    \pgfmathsetbasenumberlength{2}% try 3, 4, ...
    \pgfmathbasetodec\testvalue{\the\value{mycounter}}{10}%
    \testvalue
    \stepcounter{mycounter}%
}}

\begin{document}

\test

\test

\test

\test

\test

\test

\test

\test

\test

\test

\test


\end{document}
```

Please also see the PGF manual section 66 *Number Printing* which should also be interesting for you.

Comment: Where should I use `\pgfmathsetbasenumberlength{2}` if I want some counters used within `tikzpicture` to be with 2 digits?

Comment: @Sigur: Try it at the beginning right after `\begin{tikzpicture}`.

Comment: I tried \pgfmathsetbasenumberlength{3}. How can I get 001 with the firsr \test?

Comment: I tried \pgfmathsetbasenumberlength{3}. How can I get 001 with the firsrt \test? Because I got 000 with the first \test.

Comment: @toandhsp: Simply move the `\stepcounter{mycounter}%` to the front inside the macro.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a command that does it:

```
\newcommand\z[1]{\ifnum #1 < 10 0\fi #1}
```

Example:

```
\the\year-\z{\the\month}-\z{\the\day}
```

Comment: This is the definition of `\two@digits` in LaTeX: `\def\two@digits#1{\ifnum#1<10 0\fi\number#1}` :)

Comment: Please advise on the way(s) that may distinguish the method proposed by you from the one proposed by @egreg in his (accepted) answer. E.g., is it material that you use `\ifnum#1` whereas egreg used `\ifnum\value{#1}`?

Comment: @Mico that, and mine is wrapped in a command. I did find his useful, but I cant see people wanting to use it outside of the context I have provided