# makeindex - sorting by page number

Tags: indexing

I'm trying to create an index of notation for my paper.
I'd like to sort the index items chronologically by order of appearance.
In other words, if I have the symbol `$Z$` occurring on the second page,
the symbol `$C$` on the `8th` page and the symbol `$P$` on the last page
I would like the index to appear as

```
Z, 2 
C, 8
P, 97
```

Do you know how to do it automatically?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

It is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.  I realize it is not complicated but any time you can save those trying to help would be helpful.

Answer (score 5):

here's an approach that uses labels for the symbols and `\pageref` to keep them in input order.  the `\pageref`s need to be expanded before writing to the `.idx` file; ordinarily index material is written out verbatim.  this even permits multiple page references to the same symbol; in such a case, only the first appearance should get a label.

the routine needs some more work, since at the moment it trims off leading zeros from `\pageref` numbers, so if there are any entries on pages 1-9 they will be out of order in an index for a book of up to 99 pages, etc.  (it would probably be best to normalize on 3-digit page numbers.)  i'll work on that when time permits, but if someone else gets there first, go for it!

i'm also not sure what would happen with a symbol first introduced in a preface, or on some other page numbered with roman numerals.  another open problem.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\newcommand{\xindex}[2]{\expandafter\index\expandafter{\pageref{#1}#2}}
\begin{document}
\chapter{One}
some text $Z$\label{not:Z}\xindex{not:Z}{@$Z$} some more text.

\newpage
some text $C$\label{not:C}\xindex{not:C}{@$C$} some more text.

\newpage
some text $P$\label{not:P}\xindex{not:P}{@$P$} some more text.
and a second reference to a symbol that first appeared on a previous page
$C$\xindex{not:C}{@$C$} some more text.

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is great! Perhaps [How to output a counter with leading zeros?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30930/5764) might help.

Comment: @Werner -- yes, that will almost certainly help, only i haven't got time now to pursue it.  (i knew that had been solved somewhere; the "how to get that page number into the `.idx` file" was the more interesting part.  even though i don't think it's a very good way to arrange a symbols index.)  thanks for the link.