# nomenclature in a specific way

Tags: nomenclature

I want to make my nomenclature using `nomencl` to look like

[image]

taken from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54542/nomenclature-sorting-sort-by-number) but I have no idea how to do it.

How would the `nomencl.cfg` file have to look like, and would I what changes would I have to make to the `nomencl.ist` file?

Comment: I'd suggest rather to use [`glossaries`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/glossaries) than `nomencl`. The former is much easier to customize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{typearea}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[refpage]{nomencl}
\def\pagedeclaration#1{\dotfill\nobreakspace#1}
\makenomenclature

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]
\nomenclature{$a$}{Acceleration}
\nomenclature{$F$}{Force}
\nomenclature{$M$}{Mass}
\clearpage
\lipsum[6]
\nomenclature{$c$}{Speed of Light}
\nomenclature{$E$}{Energy}

\renewcommand{\nomname}{List of Notations}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\nomname}
\printnomenclature

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks, thats very simple and is exactly what i want, even only a `nomencl.cfg` file :)

Answer (score 3):

The following code reproduces exactly the one in the figure:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[intoc,refpage]{nomencl}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\renewcommand{\nomname}{List of Notations}
\renewcommand*{\pagedeclaration}[1]{\dotfill\hyperpage{#1}}
\makenomenclature

\begin{document}

\printnomenclature[1.5cm]   % Change the value between square brackets
                            % to increase space between symbols and descriptions

\clearpage

\[F=ma\]

\nomenclature{$F$}{Force}
\nomenclature{$a$}{Acceleration}

\clearpage

\[E=MC^2\]

\nomenclature{$E$}{Energy}
\nomenclature{$M$}{Mass}
\nomenclature{$c$}{Speed of Light}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Some remarks:

The package option `intoc` inserts the "List of Notations" in the TOC without any need for a line like:

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\nomname}
```

You need to run the following sequence to get correct references (assuming your `.tex` file is named `yourfile.tex`:

> pdflatex yourfile
>
> makeindex -s nomencl.ist -t yourfile.nlg -o yourfile.nls yourfile.nlo
>
> pdflatex yourfile
>
> makeindex -s nomencl.ist -t yourfile.nlg -o yourfile.nls yourfile.nlo
>
> pdflatex yourfile