# Change subsection number increment from .1 to .01 -eg 1.02,1.03, etc

Tags: sectioning, numbering

As the title states, I would like the subsections to increment by .01 instead of .1.  Any help would be greatly appreciated. thank you.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\begin{document}

\title{APA Ethics Code}
\author{Author}
\date{Today}
\maketitle

\section*{Preamble}
Psychologists are committed to increasing scientific and professional knowledge of behavior and people's understanding of themselves and other antd to the use of such knowledge to improve the condition of individuals, organizations,a and society.  Psychologists respect and protect civil and human rights and the central importance of freedom of inquiry and expression in research, teaching, and publication.  The strive to help the public in developing informed judgements and choices concerning human behavior.  In doing so, they perform many roles, such as researcher, educator, diagnostician,therapist, supervisor, consultant, administrator, social interventionist, and expert witness.  The Ethics Code provides a common set of principals and standards upon which psychologists build their professional and scientific work.

This Ethics Code is intended to provide specific standards to cover most situations encountered by psychologists.  It has as its goals the welfare and protection of the individuals and groups with whom psychologists work and the education of members, students, and the public regarding ethical standards of the discipline.

The development of a dynamic set of ethical standards for psychologist's' work-related conduct requires a personal commitment and lifelong effort to act ethically, to encourage ethical behavior by students, supervisees, employees, and colleagues; and to consult with others concerning ethical problems.

\section*{General Prinicipals}
This section consists of General Principles.  General Principles, as apposed to Ethical Standards, as aspirational in nature.  Their intent is to guide and inspire psychologists toward the very highest ethical ideals of the profession.  General Principles, in contrast to Ethical Standards, do not represent obligations and should form the basis for imposing sanctions.  Relying upon General Principles for either of these reasons distorts  both their meaning and purpose.

\subsection*{Principal A: Beneficence and Nonmaleficence}
Psychologist strive to benefit those with whom they work and take care to do no harm.  In their professional actions psychologists seek to safeguard the welfare and rights of those with whom they interact professionally and other affected persons, and the welfare of animal subjects of research.  When conflicts occur among psychologists; obligations or concerns, they attempt to resolve these conflicts in a responsible fashion that avoids or minimizes harm.  Because psychologists; scientific and professional judgments and actions may affect the lives of others, they are alert to and guard against personal, financial, social, organizational, or political factors that might lead to misuse of their influence.  Psychologists strive to be aware of the possible effect of their own physical and mental health on their ability to help those with whom they work.

\subsection*{Principle B: Fidelity and Responsibility}
Psychologist establish relationships of trust with whom they work.  They are aware of their professional and scientific responsibilities to society and to the specific communities in which the work.  Psychologists uphold professional standards of conduct , clarify their professional roles and obligations, accept appropriate responsibility for their behavior, and seek to manage conflicts of interest that could lead to exploitation or harm.  Psychologists consult with, refer to, or cooperate with other professionals and institutions to the extent needed to serve the best interests of those with whom they work.  They are concerned about the ethical compliance of their colleagues' scientific and professional conduct.  Psychologists strive to contribute a portion of their professional time for little or no compensation or personal advantage.

\subsection*{Principle C: Integrity}
Psychologists seek to promote accuracy, honesty, and truthfulness in the science teaching, and practice of psychology.  In these activities psychologists do not steal, cheat, or engage in fraud, subterfuge, or intentional misrepresentation of fact.  psychologists strive to keep their promises and to avoid unwise or unclear commitments.  In situations in which deception may be ethically justifiable to maximize benefits and minimize harm, psychologists have a serious obligation to consider the need for, the possible consequences of, and their responsibility to correct any resulting mistrust or other harmful effects that arise form the use of such techniques.
\subsection*{Justice}
 Psychologists recognize that fairness and justice entitle all persons to access to and benefit from the contributions of psychology and to equal quality in the processes, procedures, and services being conducted by psychologists.  Psychologists exercise reasonable judgement and take precautions to ensure that their potential biases, the boundaries of their competence, and the limitations of their expertise do not lead to or condone unjust practices.
\section*{ETHICAL STANDARDS}

\subsection{Resolving Ethical Issues}
\end{document}
```

Comment: And if the counter reaches three-digit values, how should it be displayed?

Comment: Reference: [How to output a counter with leading zeros?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30930/5764)

Comment: The issue with the three digits does not appear to come up in the document.

Comment: Here is my current workaround that seems to work.  \subsection*{1.01\hspace{0.3in}Resolving Ethical Issues}

Comment: Werner,  I looked at that but I was not looking for leading zeros like that, but how to set the counter so it increments at .01.  Thanks.

Comment: Why do you use `\subsection*` and manual counters? That is error-prone. Why don't you use `\subsection` and let LaTeX do the numbering for you in the desired formatting?

Comment: I would assume that it would go to 1.100, 1.101, etc though not 2.00 if it were to go up that high.   It is a list of ethical standards so it is not an issue.  I want the font to be the subsection font and the sections just like they are not numbered.

Comment: So you want unnumbered sections and subsections going 1.01, 1.02,...? What do the initial 1 stands for?

Comment: Please see the last example in my updated answer. Is something like that what you want?

Answer (score 11):

You can redefine `\thesubsection` and use `\two@digits` for the `subsection` counter:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection.\two@digits{\arabic{subsection}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Test Section One}
\subsection{Test Subsection One}
\subsection{Test Subsection Two}
\section{Test Section Two}
\subsection{Test Subsection One}
\subsection{Test Subsection Two}

\end{document}
```

[image]

From the comments, apparently the requirement is to have unnumbered sections, but numbered subsections; this can be easily achieved using the `titlesec` package:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{}{0em}{}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection.\two@digits{\arabic{subsection}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Test Section One}
\subsection{Test Subsection One}
\subsection{Test Subsection Two}
\section{Test Section Two}
\subsection{Test Subsection One}
\subsection{Test Subsection Two}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice. Never seen `\two@digits` before.