# animate graphic with decreasing numbers and missing 0

Tags: animate

I want to animate different png-files into one graphic in LaTeX. I use:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{animate}

\begin{document}
\frame{
\frametitle{Monte Carlo Simulation - 22 trading days, 1000 simulations}
\vspace{-0.5cm}
\begin{center}
\animategraphics[scale=0.5,autoplay]{5}{3d}{211}{1}
\end{center}
}

\end{document}
```

So the decreasing from 211 to 210 and so on works, but the problem is, that LaTeX e.g. searches for the file "3d099":

```
! Package animate Error: Neither of the files
(animate)                `3d099.pdf',
(animate)                `3d099.mps',
(animate)                `3d099.png',
(animate)                `3d099.jpg',
(animate)                `3d099.jpeg',
(animate)                `3d099.jbig2',
(animate)                `3d099.jb2',
(animate)                `3d099.jp2',
(animate)                `3d099.j2k' or
(animate)                `3d099.jpx',
(animate)                could be found.
(animate)                Wrong file type? Mis-spelled file name?.

See the animate package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.865 }

?
```

But the file name is "3d99.png", so what do I have to change, that LaTeX does it correct?

Comment: I strongly recommend to use zero-padded-digit filenames when dealing with animations. That is, if you have 11 files, names should be `base00`, `base01`, ... `base10`. Besides from solving this particular case, it will simplify most things (as encoding a movie for instance).

Comment: +1 It seems you detected a bug. Please use zero-padded file numbers in case of down-counting, for now. Will be fixed asap.

Comment: Fixed in today's version [2012/12/06].

Comment: See [How to output a counter with leading zeros?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30930/5764)