# Create custom counter

Tags: counters

I want in a document of mine to keep a lot of notes so I would like to create a custom counter so every note to be numbered like this:

**0001**

**0002**

**0003**

**0004**

(They are deliberately bold as this is the style I would like)

I would like the counter to work like the enumerate environment so to add a keyword in front of the note I want to number and also to be able to reset it.

The reasons I don't use the enumerate environment are:

1. I want the numbers to be bold
2. I want custom formatting of the numbers i.e. 0001 etc...
3. I really want to see how I can create something like that.

Comment: Do you mean 'create' your own from scratch, or use a package like `fmtcount`?

Comment: @jon I had no idea that there was a package...Also I don't really know if it is difficult or not. Basically I thought that a counter could be pretty simple if you know what you are doing...

Comment: Related (probably duplicate, since the main issue here is formatting the counter.) You can use it in an environment as you see fit. [How to output a counter with leading zeros?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30930/2693)

Comment: Well, creating a counter is dead easy: in LaTeX, just `\newcounter{xyz}` creates a counter called `xyz`. Padding zeroes so you can get output like: `0001`, `0014`, `0589`, `9999`. is a more tricky.

Comment: @jon For simplicity's sake I can compromise. How can it be used?

Comment: I think Heiko's answer is straightforward enough. ... No?

Comment: @jon I hadn't seen it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For example, with including the boldness into the appearance of the counter:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{custom}
\renewcommand*{\thecustom}{%
  \textbf{%
    \ifnum\value{custom}<1000 0\fi
    \ifnum\value{custom}<100 0\fi
    \ifnum\value{custom}<10 0\fi
    \arabic{custom}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\thecustom,
\refstepcounter{custom}\thecustom,
\refstepcounter{custom}\thecustom
\label{abc}

\setcounter{custom}{123}\thecustom,
\setcounter{custom}{7654}\thecustom,
ref: \ref{abc}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

An alternative would be to make the numbers bold in the markup macros for the notes only. Then the referenced numbers would appear in normal font.

Comment: Thank you! Every time I have to increase the counter I have to right `\refstepcounter{custom}\thecustom`?

Comment: @Adam The value of the counter can also be changed by `\stepcounter{<counter>}` or `\addtocounter{<counter>}{<amount>}`. Only `\refstepcounter` allows the counter to be referenced and `\label` with `\ref` will work for this counter.