# How can I make this factor numbering to repeat and dynamic increment + 1 to several pages?

Tags: tables, numbering, counters

[image: output]
[image: facture numbering]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm,top=1.2cm]{geometry} % géométrie de la page.
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}   % permet juste d’utiliser une nouvelle norme LATEX concernant le codage des caractères.
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  % permet de taper directement à l’écran, dans le fichier *.tex, les caractères accentués.
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb,amsthm} % permettent d’obtenir des caractère mathématiques (de toute beauté!).
\usepackage[frenchb, english]{babel} % permet de spécifier au compilateur que l’on désire taper son document en français.
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{diagbox}
%\usepackage[tikz,pst]{pas-stat}
%\usepackage{caption}
%\usepackage[table]{xcolor}  
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{mathptmx}


\begin{document}
{\centering
    {\huge\underline{\textbf{Ets Dramé Electronique}}}
    \begin{center}
        Vente en Gros et Détail Appareils Electroniques - Informatiques - Téléphones Portables-Ordinateurs\\
        Accessoires - Multimedia - GSM - PDA - Console de jeu-Logiciels - Maintenance Informatique - Décodage\\
        Place de l'indépendance $ \times $ Rue Amadou A. Ndoye - Centre Commercial la Rotonde \vspace{5pt}\\
        Tél: $ +221 \ 33 \ 123 \ 45 \ 67 $ - \ Mob: $ +221\ 77\ 123 \ 45\ 67 $ \ - $ +221\ 33\ 123\ 45\ 67 $   \\
        Email: email@gmail.com  -  www.etsdrameelectronique.com \\
        \vspace{1cm}
        \textbf{FACTURE N $ \degres \  0001 $ }
    \end{center}    
}

\vspace{.3cm}
\hspace{9cm} Dakar, le \dotfill    

Client:    \dotfill  \dots \, Tél:  \dotfill 



\vspace{.7cm}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}|p{7cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|}
    \hline
     QUANTITE & DESIGNATION  &  P.UNITAIRE  & P.TOTAL   \\ \hline
    &  &   &      \\ \hline
    &  &   &        \\ \hline
    &  &   &         \\ \hline  
    &  &   &        \\ \hline       
    TOTAL GENERAL &  &   &       \\ \hline  
\end{tabular}
\vspace{.2cm}\\
\begin{centering}
    \hspace{2pt} Arrêtée la présente note de prix à la somme de: \dotfill \\
    \dotfill
\end{centering} 

\vspace*{1cm}

\hrule
\vspace*{1cm}
{\centering
    {\huge\underline{\textbf{Ets Dramé Electronique}}}
    \begin{center}
        Vente en Gros et Détail Appareils Electroniques - Informatiques - Téléphones Portables-Ordinateurs\\
        Accessoires - Multimedia - GSM - PDA - Console de jeu-Logiciels - Maintenance Informatique - Décodage\\
        Place de l'indépendance $ \times $ Rue Amadou A. Ndoye - Centre Commercial la Rotonde \vspace{5pt}\\
        Tél: $ +221 \ 33 \ 123 \ 45 \ 67 $ - \ Mob: $ +221\ 77\ 123 \ 45\ 67 $ \ - $ +221\ 33\ 123\ 45\ 67 $   \\
        Email: email@gmail.com  -  www.etsdrameelectronique.com \\
        \vspace{1cm}
        \textbf{FACTURE N $ \degres \  0002 $ }
    \end{center}    
}

\vspace{.3cm}
\hspace{9cm} Dakar, le \dotfill    

Client:    \dotfill  \dots \, Tél:  \dotfill 



\vspace{.7cm}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}|p{7cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|}
    \hline
    QUANTITE & DESIGNATION  &  P.UNITAIRE  & P.TOTAL   \\ \hline
    &  &   &      \\ \hline
    &  &   &        \\ \hline
    &  &   &         \\ \hline  
    &  &   &        \\ \hline       
    TOTAL GENERAL &  &   &       \\ \hline  
\end{tabular}
\vspace{.2cm}\\
\begin{centering}
    \hspace{2pt} Arrêtée la présente note de prix à la somme de: \dotfill \\
    \dotfill
\end{centering}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I want the numbering after the ** FACTURE** to increase by one dynamically.

Comment: Do you know that there exist packages for this task? [`facture`](http://ctan.org/pkg/facture) (french documentation and xelatex) and [`invoice`](http://ctan.org/pkg/invoice) (pdflatex)

Comment: I am going to consult the documentation thanks.

Comment: In ``\usepackage[frenchb, english]{babel}``, you should put ``frenchb`` last as the main language is French.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using counters is the way to go here. I've simplified your code as well, making the invoice setting part of a macro.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=1.5cm,top=1.2cm,paper=a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  % permet de taper directement à l’écran, dans le fichier *.tex, les caractères accentués.
\usepackage{mathptmx,eqparbox}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\newcounter{facture}
\renewcommand{\thefacture}{% https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30930/5764
  \ifnum\value{facture}<10 000%
  \else\ifnum\value{facture}<100 00%
  \else\ifnum\value{facture}<1000 000\fi\fi\fi
  \arabic{facture}}
\newcommand{\insertfacture}{%
\stepcounter{facture}% New facture
\begin{center}
  {\huge\bfseries\underline{Ets Dramé Electronique}}

  \vspace{\baselineskip}

  Vente en Gros et Détail Appareils Electroniques - Informatiques - Téléphones Portables-Ordinateurs    \\
  Accessoires - Multimedia - GSM - PDA - Console de jeu-Logiciels - Maintenance Informatique - Décodage \\
  Place de l'indépendance $ \times $ Rue Amadou A. Ndoye - Centre Commercial la Rotonde                 \\[.5\baselineskip]
  Tél: $ +221 \ 33 \ 123 \ 45 \ 67 $ - \ Mob: $ +221\ 77\ 123 \ 45\ 67 $ \ - $ +221\ 33\ 123\ 45\ 67 $  \\
  Email: email@gmail.com  -  www.etsdrameelectronique.com \\[1cm]
  \textbf{FACTURE No \thefacture}
\end{center}    

\vspace{\baselineskip}

\hspace*{.5\textwidth}\eqmakebox[rtag][r]{Dakar, le} \dotfill

\vspace{.5\baselineskip}

\makebox[.5\textwidth][l]{Client: \dotfill}\eqmakebox[rtag][r]{Tél:} \dotfill

\vspace{.7cm}

\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}|p{7cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|}
    \hline
     QUANTITE & DESIGNATION  &  P.UNITAIRE  & P.TOTAL   \\ \hline
    &  &   &      \\ \hline
    &  &   &        \\ \hline
    &  &   &         \\ \hline  
    &  &   &        \\ \hline       
    TOTAL GENERAL &  &   &       \\ \hline  
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}

Arrêtée la présente note de prix à la somme de: \dotfill

\vspace{.5\baselineskip}

\dotfill
}

\newcommand{\insertrule}{\par
  \vspace*{1cm}
  \hrule\par
  \vspace*{1cm}}

\begin{document}

\insertfacture
\insertrule
\insertfacture

\clearpage

\insertfacture
\insertrule
\insertfacture

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great! you simplified it for me thanks @Werner.

Comment: @OusseynouDiagne: A design change falls outside the scope of this question. You'll have to ask a [follow-up question](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2117/5764) and include details of what you've tried.

Comment: Ok, hope they will not consider it as a duplicate question.