# Can I number a page from 1 to 9 as 01 to 09?

Tags: typography

Is there a way of adding a 0 to page numbers (or any other counter, for that matter) from 1 to 9?

I wanted to number those pages as 01, 02,...,09, 10, 11,...

This is for design purposes only.

Comment: You can give the `padcount` package a try.

Comment: See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30930/121799). `\renewcommand{\thepage}{\ifnum\value{page}<10 0\fi\arabic{page}}`