# Tikz: Zero-padding node labels?

Tags: tikz-pgf, labels

I define an array in the following way:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\n{10}
  \pgfmathparse{int(\n-1)}
  \foreach \x in {0,...,\pgfmathresult} {
    \foreach \y in {0,...,\pgfmathresult} {
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\nodelabel}{\x + \y*\n}
      \node at (\x,\y) (\x) {c\nodelabel};
    }
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

How can can I zero-pad the node labels such that I get `c001`, `c010` etc.?

Comment: `\node at (\x,\y) (\x) {c0\nodelabel};`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. For your future questions, please don't post code fragments. Instead put them into complete compilable documents as I did in my answer. This makes it a lot easier for people to help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another solution with `siuntix`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\n{10}
  \pgfmathparse{int(\n-1)}
  \foreach \x in {0,...,\pgfmathresult} {
    \foreach \y [evaluate=\y as \ni using {int(\x+\y*\n)}] in {0,...,\pgfmathresult} {
            \node at (\x,\y) {c\num[minimum-integer-digits=3]{\ni}};
    }
  }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Adapting the PGF answer given here: [How to output a counter with leading zeros?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30930/2693) we can use the same approach with your example. Instead of using `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` I've use `\pgfmathsetcounter` and then used the base conversion to pad the zeros.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcounter{nodelabel}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\n{10}
  \pgfmathsetbasenumberlength{3}
  \pgfmathparse{int(\n-1)}
  \foreach \x in {0,...,\pgfmathresult} {
    \foreach \y in {0,...,\pgfmathresult} {
      \pgfmathsetcounter{nodelabel}{\x + \y*\n}
      \pgfmathbasetodec\nodelabel{\the\value{nodelabel}}{10}%
            \node at (\x,\y) (\x) {c\nodelabel};
    }
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

### Update:

I may have misunderstood the question, because labels can be written naturally like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\n{10}
  \pgfmathparse{int(\n-1)}
  \foreach \x in {0,...,\pgfmathresult} {
    \foreach \y in {0,...,\pgfmathresult} {
      \node at (\x,\y) (\x) {c0\y\x};
    }
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Old answer:

You can use the macro `\opprint` from the `xlop` package that prints the numbers as they are written useless zeros included.
For example `00000.000` will be written `00000.000`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xlop}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\n{10}
  \pgfmathparse{int(\n-1)}
  \foreach \x in {0,...,\pgfmathresult} {
    \foreach \y in {0,...,\pgfmathresult} {
      \node at (\x,\y) (\x) {c\opprint{0\y\x}};
    }
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: array]

Comment: In fact I actually need `c001` to `c100`, so I went for Alan's first solution, as this is more general.

Comment: @loris You accepted Ignasi's answer, not Alan's. Is that a mistake on your part?

Comment: I subsequently switched to the Ignasi's solution because it avoids having to define a counter.  I'm writing LaTeX blocks within an Orgmode file, so using `\num[minimum-integer-digits=3]` seemed slightly more self-contained.  However, I have other arrays of labels to draw with different dimensions, but with continuous numbering across all arrays, so I may well need the counter after all.