# Two digit sectioning in memoir class

Tags: sectioning, numbering, memoir

I would like to have the first 1-9 numbered heading from chapter to subsubsections be two digits.

So instead of:
1 Chapter One
1.1 Section One
1.1.1 Subsection One
1.1.1.1 Subsubsection One

I would like:
01 Chapter One
01.01 Section One
01.01.01 Subsection One
01.01.01.01 Subsubsection One

After the first 9 they should just continue 10, 11, 12 etc. without a zero in front.

Comment: The question is not really `memoir` related, here is a general solution: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30932/3929, you'll need to use it in a redefinition of `\thechapter`, `\thesection` etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code of `memoir` contains

```
\renewcommand*{\thechapter}{\@arabic\c@chapter}
\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\thechapter.\@arabic\c@section}
\renewcommand*{\thesubsection}{%
              \thesection.\@arabic\c@subsection}
\renewcommand*{\thesubsubsection}{%
              \thesubsection.\@arabic\c@subsubsection}
```

so you have to replace every `\@arabic...` by `\two@digits...`

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\thechapter}{\two@digits\c@chapter}
\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\thechapter.\two@digits\c@section}
\renewcommand*{\thesubsection}{%
              \thesection.\two@digits\c@subsection}
\renewcommand*{\thesubsubsection}{%
              \thesubsection.\two@digits\c@subsubsection}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Foo}
\section{Bar}
\subsection{Baz}
\subsubsection{Bla}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ahh, didn't even know that was in the kernel

Comment: @daleif I found that out quite by accident only last week while looking for the definition of `\@firstoftwo` (I couldn't remember if it was `\long` or not). I've been using my own macro for years `:-)`

Comment: Legend. This is my favorite kind of answer; one that requires a level of understanding I can forgive myself for not having, and yet being easy to apply in practice.