# Customize LaTeX section numbers per chapter

Tags: sectioning

How can get section numbers to start at \thechapter * 100.
So we have in chapter 1:
section 100, section 101, etc

In chapter 2:
section 200, section 201, etc

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: Must people use 1.1 instead of 101, but it can be done.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30930/how-to-output-a-counter-with-leading-zeros

Comment: Are there any chapters that have 10 sections?  Are there any chapters that have 100 sections?

Comment: \newcommand{\oldchapter}{\chapter}

\renewcommand{\chapter}{

\setcounter{section}{ 100\thechapter -1}

\oldchapter

}

% something like this?  Not working!

Comment: Well, you can actually do `\setcounter{section}{\numexpr\thechapter*100-1\relax}`. Whether this is a good idea is another question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Adaptations

- calculate section number with `\the\numexpr100*\thechapter-1\relax`
- use `xpatch` to execute the `\setcounter` command after each chapter

#### Code

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xapptocmd{\@chapter}{%
    \setcounter{section}{\the\numexpr100*\thechapter-1\relax}
}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{A}

\section{A1}
\section{A2}
\chapter{B}
\section{B1}
\section{B2}
    
\end{document}
```

#### Result

[image]
[image]

Comment: Wow!  This is pretty much exactly what I was looking for!
I should be able to figure out how to get rid of extra "1" or "2" at beginning of headings, but now the numbering works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the counter to any number you want `\setcounter{section}{99}`

Comment: Great. But in chapter 2, I want \setcounter{section}{199}.

What if I have \input{chapter1} \input{chapter2} and then rearrange?  Don't want to be manually reseting counters per chapter.

How do I \setcounter{section}{ \thechapter *100 -1}